# Angular Material mat-expansion-panel opened event always returns undefined

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-material2

As you may know from angular material docs, [mat-expansion-panel](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/api) have @Output named "opened", that is emitted when the accordion item is opened. I want to catch that opened event and identify which panel was opened. But this simple code (below) always returns only undefined. What did I do wrong? Is this output emits only undefined or did I miss something? Material docs says nothing about that situation.

**component.html**

```
<mat-accordion multi>
  <mat-expansion-panel (opened)="openGroup($event)" *ngFor="let element of Data">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        <ul class="nav-tabs">
          <li class="col-xs-3">{{element.param1}}</li>
          <li class="col-xs-5">{{element.param2}}</li>
          <li class="col-xs-3">{{element.param3}}</li>
        </ul>
      </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>

    <div>
      <p>{{element.content}}</p>
    </div>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

**component.ts**

```
Data = [
  // This returns from backend, this is only for show that the Data is not empty
  { /* some data here*/ },
  { /* some data here*/ },
  { /* some data here*/ }
];

openGroup(e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

Answer (score 19):

This is by design; the [docs site](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/api#MatExpansionPanel) specifies that the type of the `opened` event is `void`, so the event contains nothing. If you want to have the same event handler for multiple expansion panels, you could use something like this:

```
<mat-expansion-panel (opened)="openGroup('expansion1')"></mat-expansion-panel>
<mat-expansion-panel (opened)="openGroup('expansion2')"></mat-expansion-panel>
```

or, maybe better for your case:

```
<mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let element of Data" (opened)="openGroup(element.someProp)">
```